# Equality Question & Probability

Tags: probability, inequality

$Y$ is a binomial distribution $(100, 0.5)$.

$P(|Y-50|\geq 2) = 1 - P(49 \leq Y \leq 51)$
...

I was reading these solutions in an exercise and was wondering how they came up with the next line. I thought the line should be $= 1 - P(48\leq Y\leq 52)$. Can anyone explain this?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It clearly says $\Pr(|Y-50|\ge 2$. So who qualifies? Certainly $Y=52$ does, since it is true that $2\ge 2$. Also, $53,54,\dots$ all qualify, as do $48, 47,\dots$.

So who **doesn't** qualify? Only $51$, $50$, and $49$.

Comment: thank you for the explanation